# using bootstrap modal in a Table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap modal to change the value of each cell in a Table. What i am failng to do is once the modal is open, i want to have a button inside the modal that opens the same modal but for a differnt cell, instead of closing the modal and opening it again. any idea guys..this is a bit adavnce, so i will be thankful for any clues.

i am trying to use data-id to give an id to each  since that is where the click event is to cahnge the cell data.

data-id="cursist.ID"

```
    <td><i class="fal fa-user fa-2x"></i></td>
    <td>{{ cursist.firstname }} {{ cursist.lastname }}</td>

    <td data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#exampleModalCenter" 
    class="text-center" 
    v-for="x in lessen"
     data-id="cursist.ID" 
     v-on:click="changeParticipatie(x, cursist)">

    </td>
    <div class="modal fade" 
    id="exampleModalCenter" 
    tabindex="-1" 
    role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" 
    aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">header modal</h5>

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>

                </div>

            </div>
     <div class="modal-footer  ">
    <i :class="icons.ARROW_LEFT"></i> <!-- right arrow to to next row-->
  <i data-dismiss="modal"  :class="icons.ARROW_RIGHT" ></i><!-- left arrow 
   to go to prev row-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</tr>
```

I think somehow i need to tell the modal once the right arrow button is clicked to go a find the next  value of the table row.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to use "v-bind:id = 'uniqueid'" for each td tag, like this, we can identify each row of a given column in the v-for loop. then using a bit of jQuery in order to trigger each cell . like this:

```
const button = document.getElementById(id); 
button.click(); 
$("#exampleModalCenter").modal("show");
```